# Searching app users

Tags: search, graph, facebook-fql

I want to create a dating app where the app user would search for matches based on gender, age, and current city, even if those matches are not friends. I'm assuming that there's no way to search all the app users without providing a UID;is there?

Would I need to store those variables in my DB, and then use each UID to get its respective profile info?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can only get the app users from the authorized user, but not just all of them. And for a dating app profile, all users might want to have their own profile stored in the database, with additional info (not available in Facebook). But be careful with privacy, whenever you store any personal data, let the user review and edit it first.

Comment: My ideal is to store nothing other than the UID, but then I'll only be able to return search results based on the user's friends. If I just store the gender, birthday and location I can just return the rest of the profile directly from FB. Am I making sense here (I'm not really a developer)?

Comment: see my answer, it does not work like that with just the user id. - no offense, but why are you creating a dating app if you are not really a developer? there´s zoosk already, and several other dating apps, you know ;) - meaning: the competition is pretty tough, and there´s a LOT.

Comment: I can plug any user id into graph explorer and get their public info, and whatever else they've given me permission to see - so what did I get wrong? Regarding the dating app, I've got my own niche - www.jcoach.com -- and a bit of a platform. The actual coding is the easy part, especially since my requirements are basic - it's the packaging and marketing that makes or breaks things, as you know ;)

Comment: the public info, yes ;) - and you have to know the user id, no browsing included. basic info is NOT personal stuff like current city, think about privacy.

Comment: only if they've signed into the app and have given you permissions!

Comment: yes, but still: a user is (and should always be) as anonymous as possible for you and other users. so you cannot just access the data of a user while he is offline, except you store the access token and stuff, but i would not go that way...

Comment: But once I sign into an app and give permissions, I don't have to renew those permissions. Anyone who signs onto a dating app by definition wants their profile info to be seen by other app users.

Comment: "The Facebook SDK for JavaScript automatically handles access token storage and tracking of login status, so apps using it do not need to create their own mechanisms for doing so..."

Comment: an access token is valid for 2 hours, you can only extend it to a maximum of 60 days. that being said, the JS SDK handles storage of the access token on the client, yes. it just means that you don´t have to add the token on your own for every api call, BUT it will get added by the sdk. nevertheless, it is a fact that you cannot just browse through all your app users without storing their info in a database on your own.